# Why is my code skipping the 1st date for finding the next day?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm supposed to make code that shows the next day, and this works except for the months that end in 31. For example, when I enter 3/31/2000, it gives me 4/2/2000 and skips the first day? I'm not sure why?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lab53;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class Lab53 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int year, month, day;                        
        System.out.println("Enter year/month/day");
        year = keyboardInput.nextInt();                
        month = keyboardInput.nextInt();               
        day = keyboardInput.nextInt();                 

        if ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12))    
        {              
            day=thirtyOneDaysMonth(day);      
            if(day==1 && month==12){          
                ++year;                       
                month=1;                      
            }
            else if(day==1 && month!=12)      
                ++month;                    
        }

        if ((month==2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))     
        {
            day=thirtyDaysMonth(day);              
            if(month==2 && isLeapYear(year))       
            {

                if(day>29)                          
                {
                    ++month;                       
                    day=1;                         
                }
            }
            else if( day>28 && month==2)           
            {
                ++month;                            
                day=1;                             
            }
            else                           
            {

                if(day==1)                       
                {
                    ++month;                            
                    day=1;                             
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The next date is:"+ month + "/" + day + "/" + year);  
    }  

    public static int thirtyOneDaysMonth(int day) 
    {
        if(day==31)                              
            day=1;
        else
            ++day;                              
        return day;
    }

    public static int thirtyDaysMonth(int day) 
    {
        if(day==30)                             
            day=1;
        else
            ++day;                              
        return day;
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) 
    {
        if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `if ((month==2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))` to `else if ((month==2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))`.

On a day = 31 you're updating the month in your if statement. Then you leave the if but then enter your next if statement that handles months with 30 days. Your code then increments the day again.

Answer (score 0):

Because after the first `if` has increased `3/31/2000` to `4/1/2000` the second `if` is evaluated which will again increase the day. Make the second `if` an `else if` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of month==3 and day==31, day is bumped back to 1 by

```
day=thirtyOneDaysMonth(day);
```

then the month is bumped up by

```
else if(day==1 && month!=12)      
                ++month;
```

then the next if statement is true because now month == 4

```
if ((month==2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))
```

connecting it to the previous if statement with an else if will fix the issue

```
else if ((month==2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))
```